# remove items from 2 dictionaries python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following dictionaries:

```
a = {'f': 2, 'u': 210, 'the': 100, 'too': 300, 'my': 199, 'is': 2466, 'and': 3787}
b = {'f': 9, 'u': 17, 'o': 14, 'the': 23, 'yy': 7, 'and': 12}
```

I want to remove similar keys from  both dictionaries.

I have the following code:

```
    for item in a:
        if item in b.keys():
            del a[item]
```

The code is similar to modify dictionary b.

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "None", line 4, in <module>
builtins.RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Is there any way to solve this without using  deepcopy, dict.has_key, zip or any modules? Also, the dictionaries can be of any length.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can iterate over `list(dict)`. This returns a list of keys. In Python2 you can also use `dict.keys()`.

```
for item in list(a):
    if item in b:   #Don't use b.keys() here, it is slow.
        del a[item]
```

Comment: Can you (briefly) clarify why using `b.keys()` in the inner loop slows it down?

Comment: The question title says "python 3", so I think you'd need `list(a)`.  And since we're using python 3, `b.keys()` should be fast too (compared to a list, I mean.)

Comment: @BlackVegetable `.keys()` returns a View Object in Python3, and the `in` operator works slightly slow on a View object compared to a simple `key in dict` search.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [dictionary comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
>>> a = {'f': 2, 'u': 210, 'the': 100, 'too': 300, 'my': 199, 'is': 2466, 'and': 3787}
>>> b = {'f': 9, 'u': 17, 'o': 14, 'the': 23, 'yy': 7, 'and': 12}
>>> a = {k:v for k,v in a.items() if k not in b}
>>> a
{'is': 2466, 'my': 199, 'too': 300}
>>>
```